# Add a range to email body with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am attempting to send emails through Outlook with Excel VBA.

I found code online and have entered my own values.

I get

> run-time error '13' "type mismatch".

I am attempting to add a range to the email body. The original code added a single cell's value.

```vb
Sub SendEmails()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' Create a reference to the Outlook application
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' Set the worksheet where your data is located
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3") ' Change "Sheet2" to your sheet name

    ' Find the last row with data in column A
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through each row with data
    For i = 2 To LastRow ' Assuming the header is in row 1
        ' Create a new email
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        ' Set email properties
        With OutMail
            ' Set the email address from Column D
            .To = ws.Cells(73, 12).Value
            ' Set the subject with the Invoice ID from Column A
            .Subject = "Approval Requested -  " & ws.Cells(1, 2).Value
            ' Create the email body with the requested information
            .Body = "Hi, " & ws.Cells(73, 11).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Please kindly approve the expenses below for ws.cells(1, 2).value on the ws.cells(73, 13).value tour. Thank you!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            ws.Range("h73:i100") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Best Regards," & vbNewLine & "Aaron"

            ' Send the email
            .Send
        End With

        ' Release the email object
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    Next i

    ' Release the Outlook application object
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't add this: `ws.Range("h73:i100")` to the body. It's not text, it's an object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include that range in your body then try this. It's ugly but it works:

```
Dim h73i100 As String
Dim iRow As Long

iRow = 73
For Each c In Range("h73:i100").Cells
    If c.Row = iRow Then
        h73i100 = h73i100 & c.Value & vbTab
    Else
        h73i100 = h73i100 & vbCrLf & c.Value & vbTab
        iRow = c.Row
    End If        
Next
```

Then add `h73i100` to your .Body:

```
        .Body = "Hi, " & ws.Cells(73, 11).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Please kindly approve the expenses below for ws.cells(1, 2).value on the ws.cells(73, 13).value tour. Thank you!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        h73i100 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Best Regards," & vbNewLine & "Aaron"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ws.Range("h73:i100")` with `ws.Range("h73:i100").Text`.

Comment: `Text` for a range with multiple cells will return the text of the first cell. If that cell is empty or is not text, you will get back null. To support multiple cells, use `ws.Range("h73:i100").Value2` - you will get an array (row first) of all cells in the range. It is your responsibility to format it properly.  Also see the answer by Nick Abbot